# How to use the same numbering counter for everything?

Tags: numbering, counters

When writing a book, with `\documentclass{book}`.

Like (where 1 before the dot denote the section number in each chapter, but chapter number doesn't appear)

```
1.1 Definition
1.2 Lemma
1.3 Theorem
1.4 Equation
1.5 Equation
1.6 Remark
1.7 Equation
1.8 Equation
1.9 Exercise
```

and so on, everything shares the same counter, with the number on the left.  In particular, equations and theorem-like environments share the same counter.

Comment: `\numberwithin{<theorem>}{section}` where `<theorem>` is your theorem.

Comment: Please advise if the "1" in "1.1, "1.2" etc is a section- or chapter-related prefix and if the numbering should restart at the beginning of each section (or chapter).

Comment: @marmot - Your suggestion subordinates the `theorem` counter to the `section` counter, but does not force, say, `theorem` and `lemma` environments to share the same (subordinated) counter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to load the `amsthm` environment and issue the instruction `\swapnumbers`, so that the numbers are placed before the headers of the theorem-like environments. Then, issue the instructions

```
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{rem}[equation]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exe}[equation]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{defn}[equation]{Definition}
```

to assure that all theorem-like environments share the same counter, *viz.*, the `equation` counter.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{rem}[equation]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exe}[equation]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{defn}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\begin{defn}Bla bla bla \end{defn}
\begin{lem} Bla bla bla \end{lem}
\begin{thm} Bla bla bla \end{thm}
\begin{equation}1+1=2\end{equation}
\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\begin{rem} Bla bla bla \end{rem}
\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}0+0=0\end{equation}
\begin{exe} Bla bla bla \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: Suppose the `book` document class is in use and the counter of the equation and theorem-like environments is supposed to be subordinated to the `section` rather than to the `chapter` counter variable. In that case, I suggest you replace `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` with the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\makeatother
```

There may be more efficient (or, at least, less wordy) methods to achieve your formatting goal, but the code shown above gets the job done.

Comment: To place the equation numbers on the left as well, just specify the document class option `leqno`.

Comment: Nice job!  One more question,  if the documentclass is book,  instead of article,   how to delete the chapter-related prefix in 1.1.2 theorem,  chap.sect.theorem,  just keep the section-related prefix 1.2 theorem, section.theorem?

Comment: @C.Davide - If your document has `chapter`-level dividers, as is the case with the `book` document class, I would simply change `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` to `\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}`. If you were to insist on subordinating the equation (and other) numbers to the `section`, you'd get ambiguous (and hence highly confusing) cases of several equations numbered, say, "(2.2)".

Comment: @Miko - Thanks again for your advice. Yeah,  there are ambiguous issues if one insists on the section-prefix numbering in a book.  But,  technically,  is it possible to do so?

Comment: @C.Davide - Please see the update I posted to my answer.

Comment: @Miko - Great answer,  I have  been stuck on this problem for a long time, now everthing seems so clear,  Thank You So Much !

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}%%just define the remaining as like as the same
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{theorem}
Test
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
Test
\end{lemma}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This setup doesn't enforce the requirement that the numbering of the theorem-like environments should be linked to the numbering of equations.

Comment: @Mico but in his `MWE`, hope he mentioned that he didn't mention about the display equation number, I thought he mentioned the text `Equation` as like as other heading, etc.

Comment: The OP did write "In particular, equations and theorem-like environments share the same counter."